# Installing proprietary ethernet drivers in Fedora

Tags: fedora, drivers

I have an HP HDX16-1354CA Laptop that I've installed Fedora 19 on, and my ethernet port is not being detected. I am sure that it is because I have not installed the drivers for it, but I can't seem to find any proprietary ethernet drivers for linux anywhere. Is there some way to search for all proprietary drivers that match your system, like Ubuntu does with the "Additional Drivers" option? The windows equivalent to the driver that I need is the Realtek PCI-E Fast Ethernet NIC Driver.

Comment: You can find out the exact model number of your card from `lspci|grep -i ethernet`. The bad news, though, is that Ethernet is usually supported "out-of-the-box" on Linux. The only two cases I've seen where Ethernet didn't work in Linux were either because the NIC was faulty or the model wasn't supported in Linux at all.

Comment: Exactly. I'm not sure what card model is in your laptop but if it was RTL810x, you could try a Linux driver provided by Realtek at http://tinyurl.com/myjblzc .

Comment: Checked the card model:`03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)`

I also tried to get the Realtek driver from that link, but I get this error when I run it: `make: *** /lib/modules/3.10.3-300.fc19.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.`

Pretty sure it's because my model type is RTL811X, but any guidance from here?

Comment: You don't have installed kernel-devel package,  install it first and then continue with the procedure written in the readme file from the driver package.

Comment: I ran `sudo yum install kernel-devel` and it loaded a couple plugins then said "nothing to do". I then ran the autorun file again, it still said the same thing. I actually have the folder that it is referring to (`/lib/modules/3.10.3-300.fc19.x86_64/build`) I just don't know why it can't find it.